# Parsley.js - validate hidden field once visible

Tags: forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a field that is hidden on load, then is toggled to be visible, and I am trying to get Parsley.js to validate this newly visible field based on the triggers I have specified:

```
$('[data-parsley]').parsley({
  trigger: 'focusout change',
  triggerAfterFailure: 'focusout change',
  excluded: 'button,[type=button],[type=submit],[type=reset],[disabled],:hidden'
});
```

Check it out here: https://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/OJJqmZW?editors=1010

It only validates this new field on form submit, but not on the `focusout` or `change` triggers.

Is this a bug? If `excluded` only runs on first initialisation, I would have expected submitting the form to ignore it too.

I *can* work around it by toggle the field to be `disabled` when it is hidden, and remove `:hidden` from `excluded` but it does feel like this might be an issue with Parsley.

Any thoughts/help welcomed.

Thanks,

Keir